# Не запускается Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot

Есть большая проблема... Не могу запустить и правильно структурировать проект. Что только не пробовал делать... Суть в чём:
Впервые решил опробовать Hibernate + Spring. Вроде как всё настроил, база с хибернейтом работает отлично - но запустить и проверить что будет в конечном итоге в html так и не получилось.

По порядку:

**Структура проекта:**
Java
-->controller
---->MainController.java
-->dao
---->MessageDAO.java
-->model
---->Message.java
--Services
---->MessageServices.java
-->utils
---->HibernateUtil.java
-->Application.java
resources
-->templates
---->_menu.html
---->messagePage.html

-->hibernate.cfg.xml

<--pom.xml

**MainController:**

```
package controller;

import dao.MessageDAO;
import model.Message;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import java.util.List;

@Controller
public class MainController {

@Autowired
private MessageDAO messageDAO;

MainController(){}

@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String showMessage(Model model) {
    List<Message> list = messageDAO.findAll();
    model.addAttribute("Messages", list);
    return "messagePage";
}
}
```

**MessageDAO:**

```
package dao;

import model.Message;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.Transaction;
import utils.HibernateUtil;

import java.util.List;


public class MessageDAO {

public Message findById(int id){
    return 
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Message.class, id);
}

public Message findByMessage(String message){
    return 
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().get(Message.class, message);
}

public void save(Message message){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(message);
    tx1.commit();
    session.close();
}

public void update(Message message){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
    session.update(message);
    tx1.commit();
    session.close();
}

public void delete(Message message){
    Session session = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
    Transaction tx1 = session.beginTransaction();
    session.delete(message);
    tx1.commit();
    session.close();
}

public List<Message> findAll() {
    List<Message> messages = (List<Message>) 
HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession().createQuery("From 
Message").list();
    return messages;
}
}
```

**Message:**

```
package model;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table (name = "Messages")
public class Message {
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int id;

@Column
private String Message;

public Message(){}

public Message(String Message){
    this.Message = Message;
}

public String getMessage() {
    return Message;
}

public void setMessage(String message) {
    Message = message;
}

public int getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
}
```

**MessageService**

```
package Services;

import dao.MessageDAO;
import model.Message;

import java.util.List;

public class MessageService {

private MessageDAO messageDAO = new MessageDAO();

public MessageService(){}

Message findMessage(int id) {
    return messageDAO.findById(id);
}

Message findMessage(String message){
    return messageDAO.findByMessage(message);
}

public void save(Message message){
    messageDAO.save(message);
}

public void delete(Message message){
    messageDAO.delete(message);
}

public void update(Message message){
    messageDAO.update(message);
}

public List<Message> findAllMessage(){
    return messageDAO.findAll();
}
}
```

**HibernateUtil**

```
package utils;

import model.Message;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.boot.registry.StandardServiceRegistryBuilder;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;



public class HibernateUtil {
private static SessionFactory sessionFactory;

private HibernateUtil(){}

public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory(){
    if (sessionFactory == null) {
        try{
            Configuration configuration = new Configuration().configure();
            configuration.addAnnotatedClass(Message.class);
            StandardServiceRegistryBuilder builder = new 
 StandardServiceRegistryBuilder()
.applySettings(configuration.getProperties());
            sessionFactory = 
configuration.buildSessionFactory(builder.build());
        }catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception!!! " + e);
        }
    }
    return sessionFactory;
}
}
```

**Application**

```
import controller.MainController;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;


@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args);

}
}
```

**pom.XML**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>DevYuriyIva</groupId>
<artifactId>MessagesControl</artifactId>
<version>1.0</version>
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>7</source>
                <target>7</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.0.5.RELEASE</version>
</parent>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.12</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.6.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- dependencies for fixing bug when program is compiled -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.bind</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxb-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.11</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.activation</groupId>
        <artifactId>activation</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>7.0.55</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
</project>
```

И тут уже хотел проверить, правильно ли поставил разметку в html, но Spring не запустился.
**messagePage.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<title>Bank</title>
<style>
th, td {
padding: 5px;
} 
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>MESSAGES</h2>
<table border="1">
<tr>
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>MESSAGE</th>
</tr>
<tr th:each="message : ${Messages}">
    <td th:utext="${message.id}">..</td>
    <td th:utext="${message.message}">..</td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Выдает примерно следующее:

```
  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
 '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
:: Spring Boot ::        (v2.0.5.RELEASE)

2018-10-22 18:45:45.170  INFO 14728 --- [           main] Application                              
: Starting Application on Jeffrys with PID 14728 
(D:\JAVA\MessagesControl\target\classes started by Jeffrys in 
D:\JAVA\MessagesControl)
2018-10-22 18:45:45.170  INFO 14728 --- [           main] Application                              
: No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2018-10-22 18:45:45.239  INFO 14728 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Refreshing 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
AnnotationConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext@1be2019a: startup date 
[Mon Oct 22 18:45:45 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy
2018-10-22 18:45:45.423  WARN 14728 --- [           main] 
ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during 
context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web 
server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory 
bean.
2018-10-22 18:45:45.971 ERROR 14728 --- [           main] 
o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web 
server; nested exception is 
org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start 
ServletWebServerApplicationContext due to missing ServletWebServerFactory 
bean.
at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
ServletWebServerApplicationContext.onRefresh
(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:155) ~[spring-boot- 
2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.
AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:544) ~ 
[spring-context-5.0.7.RELEASE.jar:5.0.7.RELEASE]
at 
org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.
ServletWebServerApplicationContext
.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot- 
2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
at 
org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
.refresh(SpringApplication.java:780) [spring-boot- 
2.0.5.RELEASE.jar:2.0.5.RELEASE]
... 8 common frames omitted

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Проект делаю по разным гайдам, тем самым учась и запоминая что за что отвечает. Но сейчас стал в тупик и не могу доделать вывод... help plz.

Comment: Уберите зависимости : spring web, spring context. Добавьте стартер spring-boot-starter-web. Так же советую убрать версии у всех артефактов, потому что они прописаны в spring-boot-starter (parent).

Comment: Так же для таймлифа следует добавить стартер.

Comment: Никак не помогло... @aleshka-batman

Comment: добавьте корневой package и все из директории java поместите туда, должно помочь с этой ошибкой, помимо этого MessageDao используется странно, в сервисе создается новый объект,а в контроллере попытка инъекции(autowire), которая скорее всего приведет к ошибке так как подходящего спринг бина в application context'е у вас нет.

Comment: Действительно помогло создание еще одной папки... Но возникла еще одна проблема. После запуска сервера, он сразу же падает с ошибкой:
`s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@59402b8f: startup date [Tue Oct 23 15:51:18 MSK 2018]; root of context hierarchy`
и 
`o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown`
@VladMamaev

Comment: изменил зависимость в maven, запустилось. Вот только приложение не отрабатывает... Буду дальше разбираться.

Comment: @ЮрийИва конец логов мне ничего не говорит:) ищите с какой ошибкой падает. Один из вариантов я уже упомянул- это autowired дао в контролере, вы пытаете inject объекта, которого нет в application context,используйте \@Component или \@Repository на дао классе

Answer (score 3):

`SpringApplication.run(MainController.class, args)` исправьте на `SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args)`